# Adjust volume above 100% for specific application

Tags: sound, 18.04

I already know how to increase volume above 100% system wide, but I want to do this for only one application (which is always very quiet, I want to turn it up). This is my settings page for sound.[image: screenshot]

Comment: So what happens when you click the over amplification slider?

Comment: @Panther I can over amplify the system wide sound but not the application specific sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any way to over-amplify an application, so this has a similar effect. Go to Settings/Sound/Over-amplification, toggle on, and turn up the system volume. Then, open the Applications tab (in Settings/Sound) and turn down the volume for every other application. Not a perfect solution (you need to do this for every application) or what I was looking for, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Open the application you want to set with high volume.

Then go to *Settings-->Sound* (the very same page you show above) and select the tab `Applications`. Only applications that have recently played sounds will show up. Select your desired volume and enjoy.

Comment: Does not work. It is already at max volume (as are all applications). I want to over-amplify one application.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no sensible change between high and low volume for that application? What application is that?

Comment: No, the application is already at maximum volume. I want to over amplify **one** application. Toggling over amplify does not provide an option to over amplify specific applications.